# Control copy and paste with unformatted output

Tags: google-chrome, copy-paste

I wish I could Copy and Paste in my Chrome browser without outputting text with html format. I'd like a pure TXT.

Is there a soul in this world who knows the shortcut (something like control+shift+alt+tap+capslock + v) or some plugin?

The reason I want it, its because i don't want to control+paste in notepad and recopy again.
Would be awesome a generic solution for this, AKA not only to firefox.

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, as described [here](http://chrome.blogspot.com/2010/09/tip-just-text-please.html).